# How to deploy a parallel program in MATLAB which would be used in JAVA?

Tags: java, matlab, parallel-processing

I have designed a parallel program in MATLAB, and I need to deploy it into a JAVA library, so that I can use this program in eclipse. While using the deployed library, there is a problem occured, here is the error information:

```
Error using initclient (line 37)
Java exception occurred: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:339)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:390)

Error in distcomp/schema (line 11)



Error in parallel_function (line 430)



Error in readingsaad (line 18)



Error in mainfunction (line 14)


Exception in thread "main" ... Matlab M-code Stack Trace ...
file C:\Users\YANCIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Yancie Yang\mcrCache8.0\IM_5F20\toolbox\distcomp\initclient.m, name initclient, line 37.
file C:\Users\YANCIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Yancie Yang\mcrCache8.0\IM_5F20\toolbox\distcomp\@distcomp\schema.m, name schema, line 11.
file C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\compiler\mcr\matlab\lang\parallel_function.m, name parallel_function, line 430.
file C:\Users\YANCIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Yancie Yang\mcrCache8.0\IM_5F20\IM\readingsaad.m, name readingsaad, line 18.
file C:\Users\YANCIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Yancie Yang\mcrCache8.0\IM_5F20\IM\mainfunction.m, name mainfunction, line 14.
com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException: Java exception occurred: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:339)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:390)

    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.mclFeval(Native Method)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.access$600(MWMCR.java:23)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR$6.mclFeval(MWMCR.java:833)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR$5.invoke(MWMCR.java:731)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.mclFeval(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.invoke(MWMCR.java:406)
    at IM.IM.mainfunction(IM.java:213)
    at com.yancie.main.IMTest.main(IMTest.java:17)
```

why is this? Please help me... thanks in advance.

Ps I'm sure that the problem occured while using the MATLAB--"parfor", and I have deployed a another program which didn't have this problem.

Comment: For the record, I don't believe this is a duplicate - the NPE is coming from MathWorks code and appears not to be the fault of the OP. @yancie - I think you should contact MathWorks technical support about this, it might well be a bug.